Why am I getting Axios Network Error on Code that Wasn't Changed?
Could anyone give me some information about axios network error and where it might come from? I keep getting this error but I'm not sure where the error is even coming from. This is the exact error I am getting. I am getting the same error on two different projects. I don't think I changed anything about the second one for that to stop working.

I tried using a different port, updating everything.

Please Check your server and restart your project and build again

A one-line answer is not high quality.  Can you add more?  What should they check on their server? Could there be a root cause?

The AxiosError: NetworkError might be because of multiple reasons:

React: Axios Network Error
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5366
Network error with axios and react native

The only thing we can be sure is that the server did received the request, and then some issues is happening there. So, I think you should wrap your call in a try-catch, get the detailed error and then check with your BE dev to find the reason:
try {
  // the axios request
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error?.response); //--> this is the detailed response with error
}

